# Parsing QChar from QString as opposed to direct assignment

Tags: qt

Why are the results of this inconsistent?  The encoding on right is what is displayed in the debugger.  My problem right now is that c1 != c2.

```
QChar c1 = 'ç';                //==> 50087
QString str = "ç";
QChar c2 = str.at(0);          //==> 231
QChar c3 = QString(c1).at(0);  //==> 50087
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt may be misinterpreting your character by processing it as a signed short and applying [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) to it, which produces the incorrect 50087 value. If you explicitly cast the character to an unsigned character - `(uchar)'ç'` - you should get consistent results.

The following code should work for you:

```
QChar c1 = (uchar)'ç';                //==> 231
QString str = "ç";
QChar c2 = str.at(0);          //==> 231
QChar c3 = QString(c1).at(0);  //==> 231
```

However, since the character-set you're using is in the [extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ascii) range, I suggest you use either wide-character or UTF8 encoding for your source strings and characters to avoid possible ambiguity when it comes to the extended ASCII range. Characters in the extended ASCII range are interpreted according to code pages, which can result in ["character set confusion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ascii#Character_set_confusion).